# Can two Android Fragments use the same ids?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I want to have two or more Fragments which will be processed similarly. Can I reuse ids in each Fragment?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 

  <Fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
    class="com.example.DoesSomethingToTitle"

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title" />
  </Fragment>


  <Fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
    class="com.example.DoesSomethingToTitle"

    <TextView android:id="@id/title" />  <!-- same id -->
  </Fragment>

</FrameLayout>
```

And use it like this:

```
public class DoesSomethingToTitle {
    private String titletext;

    public DoesSomethingToTitle(String titletext) {
       this.titletext = titletext;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed, container, false);
        // find the title TextView and mutate it
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(titletext);
        return v;
    }
}
```

(I realize for something as simple as this, I could just specify the title string in the XML; my actual usage is more complex.)

Comment: I am not sure if questions makes sense. Could I ask why would you want to reuse ID ?

Comment: Because I want to have one class findViewById, and I want to pass the same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can I reuse ids in each Fragment?**

Yes you can.